# Keep only N first records in SQLite database, group by date

Tags: sqlite

I've a table in SQLite database which has few records for each date. I want to trim the table down by keeping only 50 records for each date. How is this possible?

Comment: *Which* 50 records? SQL tables are unordered, "first" has no meaning without specifying a sort order.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite's DELETE  has a LIMIT clause but it depends upon how your flavor of sqlite was compiled:  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html